# TAB (MapInfo) Attribute Data not Imported to shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, tab

I am trying to convert some TAB files into Shapefiles by using QGIS. After I import the TAB files, and make sure that these have the correct CRS, it is possible to observe that the spatial data can be exported into a shapefile.

However, and regardless of the tab file imported, the data in attribute table is always missing. Therefore, the only way for me to correctly import a tab file into QGIS, both geometrical and attribute data, is by using Universal Translator (UT).

[image: Attribute Tables from the same TAB and UT converted file]

Is it possible to import **both geometry and attribute tables** from TAB to SHP, using QGIS?

Here is a sample of the data I am working with (tab files). [Sample TAB file](https://www.filedropper.com/tabdata)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your tab files with a text editor, you see there is only one field. What you call attributs seems to be informations for labelling

[image]

For exemple, i open an other file (cours_eau.tab), and the import works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can study your data with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo "cut numbers.tab" -al 
INFO: Open of `cut numbers.tab'
      using driver `MapInfo File' successful.

Layer name: cut numbers
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 206
Extent: (583187.850000, 266081.960000) - (583488.020000, 266389.950000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed",
        DATUM["OSGB_1936",
            SPHEROID["Airy 1930",6377563.396,299.3249646],
            TOWGS84[375,-111,431,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
blank: String (1.0)
OGRFeature(cut numbers):1
  blank (String) =
  Style = LABEL(t:"12025",a:0.000000,s:0.655312g,c:#000000,p:1,f:"")
  POINT (583487.07 266168.230271857)
```

The report means that your MapInfo file contains text strings as labels, not as attributes. I believe it would be possible to convert the contents of labels into normal attributes with GDAL and some Python scripting.